# import apache drill to eclipse or IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, apache-drill

I'm learning apache drill now, and want to do some debug. 
Now each time, I need to recompile the whole project after any change. 
So I just want to know, can I import the whole apache drill project to eclipse or IntelliJ? How? 
I know the drill project contains some template java file which will be generated many classes at compile time, after import to eclipse/IntelliJ, is this can still working?

Comment: Have you debugged Apache Drill using Eclipse yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/compiling-drill-from-source/) have some info you might find helpful: